# ggplot2: fill space between lines with different axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm comparing the performance of two models with ROC curves, and I'd like to fill in the regions between the two curves to show where one model outperforms the other. I've tried use `geom_ribbon`, but the issue is that  both axes are different for each curve.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
##Simulate Data
set.seed(123456)
n <- 10000
q <- 0.8

#Simulate predictions
Real <- c(sample(c(0,1), n/2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-q,q)),
          sample(c(0,1), n/2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7,0.3)))

#Simulate Response
p <- c(rep(seq(0.4,0.9, length=100), 50),
       rep(seq(0.2,0.6, length=100), 50))
p2 <- c(rep(seq(0.5,0.9, length=100), 50),
        rep(seq(0.2,0.7, length=100), 50))
p <- data.frame(cbind(Real, p, p2))

#install and load package
#install.packages("pROC")
library(pROC)

#apply roc function
analysis <- roc(response=p$Real, predictor=p$p)
analysis2 <- roc(response=p$Real, predictor=p$p2)

#Plot ROC Curve
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=1-analysis$specificities,y=analysis$sensitivities)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1-analysis2$specificities,y=analysis2$sensitivities), color = "red")
```

[image: ROC plot]

How can I fill in the spaces between these two lines?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why `roc` is producing vectors of different lengths for each model. I thought there might be a way to set the number of x-values at which the ROC curve is calculated, but I couldn't find one. Instead, let's use interpolation to get y-values for each ROC curve at the same x-values.

```
library(pROC)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

#apply roc function
analysis <- roc(response=p$Real, predictor=p$p)
analysis = data.frame(x=1-analysis$specificities, y=analysis$sensitivities)

analysis2 <- roc(response=p$Real, predictor=p$p2)
analysis2 = data.frame(x=1-analysis2$specificities, y=analysis2$sensitivities)

# Use interpolation to get y-values at the same x-values for each ROC curve
dat = as.data.frame(approx(analysis, n=194))
dat = cbind(dat, y2=approx(analysis2, n=194)$y)
names(dat) = c("x", "Model 1", "Model 2")

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data=dat, aes(x, ymin=`Model 1`, ymax=`Model 2`), fill="yellow") +
  geom_line(data=melt(dat, id.var="x"), aes(x, value, colour=variable), size=0.8) +
  labs(x="1 - Specificity", y="Sensitivity", colour="") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! For those interested, if you want to shade color to differ based on which model is better, set `fill = Model 1 > Model 2` within the `aes()`.